# Is it possible to convert a 2-d array to list of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I'm writing a page ranking algorithm that uses a 2-dimension array for storing data. 1 means a page has a link to another page, 0 means that it does not. My question is:
 Is there a way to convert a 2-d `int[,]` matrix into a list of objects.

For example my matrix looks like this:

```
int[,] matrix = new int[2, 2];    
matrix[0,0] = 0    
matrix[0,1] = 1    
matrix[1,0] = 1    
matrix[1,1] = 1;
```

it produces an array:

```
0 1    
1 0
```

What I want to do is convert this matrix into a `List` of `Page` objects:

```
public class Page{         
    public string PageName {get;set;}
    public List<Page> ShowsToPages {get; set;}

    public Page(){ this.ShowsToPages = new List<Page>();}
}
```

In this scenarion I would have a `List<Page>` that contains 2 pages. And each page object would have a list, that contains all the references of Pages it shows to.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to convert a matrix into a list of objects

Comment: Each page should have a list of page references that it is pointing to. For example if we have a matrix:
01
00

First page object should have a List of Size 1, that contains a reference to the other page it is pointing to.

The second page Should have also a list of size 0, that contains no references, because it does not point to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pages = Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(0))
  .Select(i => { var page = new Page();
  page.ShowsToPages.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(1))
  .Where(j => array(i, j) != 0)); return page; }).ToList();
```